# Assets 404 Not Found in Rails Development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I'm not sure when I first started getting this message, but the error message only comes up on my development server.  The production heroku server doesn't report anything.

```
Started GET "/assets/bootstrap_and_overrides.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-06-08 16:57:30 -0700
Served asset /bootstrap_and_overrides.css - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-06-08 16:57:30 -0700
Served asset / - 404 Not Found (5ms)

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets"):
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
  railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
  railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
  railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
  railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
  railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
  thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:81:in `block in pre_process'
  thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:79:in `catch'
  thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:79:in `pre_process'
  thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:54:in `process'
  thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:39:in `receive_data'
  eventmachine (1.0.3) lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run_machine'
  eventmachine (1.0.3) lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run'
  thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/backends/base.rb:63:in `start'
  thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/server.rb:159:in `start'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:13:in `run'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/server.rb:268:in `start'
  railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
  railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
  railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
  railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
  script/rails:6:in `require'
  script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Comment: I solved the problem by adding a default_url for my Carrierwave uploads.  Somehow when I was editing my database tables, I removed some of the corresponding images for my posts.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you are trying to read the assets directory.  But the reason you don't see /assets on your dev server is that rails will serve assets from the /app/assets/stylesheets in dev mode, for items that exist, but since there is no route to /assets (check via `rake routes`) you get an error.

In production `rake assets:precompile` is performed during your upload to heroku and so the dir /public/assets is created and populated.

You can `rake assets:precompile` on your dev machine to see what happens.

Comment: In development, Rails will use the path `/assets/`. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#in-development